# Extracting a link with jmeter

Tags: xpath, onclick, jmeter, extract

So I need to delete an "onclick" dynamic link using jmeter.

Here is the sample of one of the links:

"`<a href="/dag/daaction.do?param=1678245" onclick="return delReminder()">Delete</a>`"

What I need is to extract number and post it in order to do the delete action. Every link is the same except the number.
I have tried to implement some of the solutions I've found on this site but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Peace

Comment: Why the dislikes?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with XPath you could try going for substring-after function like:

```
substring-after(//a[text()='Delete']/@href,'param=')
```

The above expression returns everything which is after `param=` text in `href` attribute of `a` HTML tag having `Delete` text.

You can test your XPath expressions against actual server response using XPath Tester tab of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image: Xpath Tester]

References:

- [substring-after Function Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after)
- [XPath 1.0 Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks but how do I combine it with url now? Or make it "click" ?
I know there is something with post processor but not sure how

Comment: add a HTTP Request sampler and use extracted variable as "Path"